# android studio flutter code indentation format?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Pls I downloaded the flutter and dart plugins in Android studio, why is there no such line
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are valid for **Android Studio and IntelliJ** respectively:

Automatically formatting code in **Android Studio and IntelliJ**
To automatically format your code in the current source code window, use `Cmd+Alt+L` (on Mac) or `Ctrl+Alt+L` (on Windows and Linux).

In addition to that, you can go to `"File/Settings,"` then search for `"Flutter"` and enable `"Show UI Guides for build methods"`:

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just tried it, it does format, but there is still no such line

Comment: thanks, I just made sure it's set as you said, but it still turns out like the updated image in the question